# Symfony form with entity

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

Hi I need a thinking help abaout form with entity class.
I have the edit function

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_product_group_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, ProductGroup $productGroup): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductGroupType::class, $productGroup);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_product_group_index', [
            'id' => $productGroup->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('admin/product_group/edit.html.twig', [
        'product_group' => $productGroup,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'scrollUp' => true,
    ]);
}
```

and I have the form Type

```
use App\Entity\ProductGroup;
use App\Entity\ProductType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductGroupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nameDe')
            ->add('nameEn')
            ->add('descriptionDe')
            ->add('descriptionEn')
            ->add('rank')
            ->add('active')
            ->add('creatDate')
            ->add('updateDate')
            ->add('productTypes', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => ProductType::class,
                // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'nameDe',
                // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
                // 'multiple' => true,
                // 'expanded' => true,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ProductGroup::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

by creating an new ProductGroup all is fin but by edit it, I cannot get the edit Form.

I get this error

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\Admin\ProductGroupController::edit() must be an instance of App\Entity\ProductGroup, instance of App\Entity\ProductType given, called in /var/www/symfony-michael-roskosch/htdocs/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php on line 150
```

This is symfony 4.3 with symfony2 i had no problems with that, can you giv me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

ok i found it

I had the wrong repositoryClass llinked by the orm annotation

```
/**
- * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductTypeRepository")
+ * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductGroupRepository")
 */
class ProductGroup
{
```

It was not a good idea to take the entity name ProductType because than you have the form ProductTypeType. After bin/console make:crud some mistakes was in the code. I don't know if I did them last night or it cames by the crud process it self.

nevermind now it works :-)